# How to detect multiple tkinter button presses simultaneously?

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

I am working on a remote game controller where there are 4 button, each representing a arrow key function to make the game work.

So, as of now the game controller works fine, the game controller is based on python TCP Socket and sends the `keyname` when pressed and `Release_keyname` when a button is released.

For example pressing button Up will send `UP` and releasing the button will send `Release_UP`to the server for imitating the keypress in a different PC.

Here is my client side code using tkinter and socket :

```
import socket
from tkinter import *

s = socket.socket()

host_ip = "127.0.0.1"

port = 1234

s.connect((host_ip,port))

root = Tk()
root.geometry ("700x512")
Left , Right = LEFT , RIGHT

def UP (event):
    data = "UP"
    s.send(data.encode())
    print(data)
def Release_UP (event):
    data = "Release_UP"
    s.send(data.encode())
    print(data)

def DOWN (event):
    data = "DOWN"
    s.send(data.encode())
def Release_DOWN (event):
    data = "Release_DOWN"
    s.send(data.encode())

def LEFT (event):
    data = "LEFT"
    s.send(data.encode())
def Release_LEFT (event):
    data = "Release_LEFT"
    s.send(data.encode())

def RIGHT (event):
    data = "RIGHT"
    s.send(data.encode())
def Release_RIGHT (event):
    data = "Release_RIGHT"
    s.send(data.encode())

button_1 = Button(text = "UP",padx = 100,pady = 100)
button_3 = Button(text = "LEFT",padx = 100,pady = 100)
button_4 = Button(text = "RIGHT",padx = 100,pady = 100)
button_2 = Button(text = "DOWN",padx = 100,pady = 100)

button_1.pack(side = TOP)
button_2.pack(side = BOTTOM)
button_3.pack(side = Left)
button_4.pack(side = Right)

button_1.bind("<ButtonPress>" , UP)
button_1.bind("<ButtonRelease>" , Release_UP)
button_2.bind("<ButtonPress>" , DOWN)
button_2.bind("<ButtonRelease>" , Release_DOWN)
button_3.bind("<ButtonPress>" , LEFT)
button_3.bind("<ButtonRelease>" , Release_LEFT)
button_4.bind("<ButtonPress>" , RIGHT)
button_4.bind("<ButtonRelease>" , Release_RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

But the game I am trying to play, also requires the left/right key to be presses simultaneously with Up key to achieve a diagonal movement.

Hence, I'm in requirement of such a GUI where two simultaneous presses of buttons can be detected but in tkinter it doesn't seem to work.

A quick resolution is using **PyGame (Finger Motion)** or **Kivy** GUI to detect multiple presses but is it possible to do the same task with **Tkinter** ?

I will be actually running the client side code on **Pydroid 3** in an Android phone and the server will be on a PC, so multiple touch is possible. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I think `pygame` is your way out. Otherwise you might need something like: `button_1.bind('<Up><Down>',lambda e: print(e.keysym))` for each possible combination

Comment: Yes you are correct, I think the only possible and best way to do it will be with pygame only.

Comment: You can try `keyboard` module.

Comment: I cannot use keyboard module because the client will be on a Android phone and the buttons need to be pressed on the GUI not on android keyboard.

Comment: What I mean is two tkinter button will be pressed at the same time on the android phone but tkinter is not detecting it.